# Custom Workflow vs Plugins execution timeout in CRM Online V9?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I need clear information on whether or not there is a 2-minute timeout for custom workflows in CRM online V9. I know that plugins are subject to the 2-minute timeout when registered in Sandbox mode, but what about custom workflows? Also, is it possible to register plugins with no isolation for CRM online?!

This is ridiculous as some processes require more than 2 minutes to complete. If I have plugins that need more time, how can I circumvent this?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dynamics 365 Online all plugins and custom workflows must be registered in the sandbox and are subject to the sandbox's 2-minute timeout.

To get around it, the recommended best practice is to enable your code to run in Azure and use an [Azure-aware plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/write-custom-azure-aware-plugin) to access it.

If you want to stray from best practices, you can persist the state (if necessary) and make the workflow call itself up to 7 times before the system's infinite loop detection shuts it down.

Comment: This is unfortunate, but I guess I will have no option but to reduce execution below 2 minutes or  enable code to run in Azure!

Thanks a lot Aron!

Comment: Yeah, it's a challenge we all have to deal with at some point. For one solution I wrote a whole routine to preserve the state to XML and store it on an note record, then in the next cycle restore the state and resume. If you're doing some kind of bulk process, external tools like Microsoft Flow, or an ETL tool like Scribe or KingswaySoft on SSIS might be worth checking into.